# Can you make any sense of Dockers error-messages?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I admit, I am a newbie in the container-world. But I managed to get docker running on my W10 with WSL2. I can also use the docker-UI and run Containers/Apps or Images. So I believe that the infrastructure is in place and uptodate.
Yet, when I try even the simplest Dockerfile, it doesn't seem to work and I don't understand the error-messages it gives:
This is Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
```

*(yes, a humble beginning - or an extremly slimmed down repro)*

```
docker build Dockerfile
[+] Building 0.0s (2/2) FINISHED
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 33B                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 33B                                                                                                                                              0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
------
 > [internal] load .dockerignore:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: error from sender: Dockerfile is not a directory
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to run `docker build -f [docker_file_name] .` (don't miss the dot at the end).

If the name of your file is `Dockerfile` then you don't need the `-f` and the filename.

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar issue, I use the docker desktop for windows. Restarted the laptop and the issue was resolved. Hope it may help someone.

Comment: tbh: Rebooting is always a good idea, but it can't fix the mis ing dot. However, in a "clean" shell you may not type the commanline again w/o the dot 

Answer (score 4):

First check Docker file name(D should be capital), then run docker build -f Dockerfile . (dot at the end).

Comment: I missed the dot in the end. Thanks

Comment: `-f`  lets you specify the name of your docker file, the default seems to be `Dockerfile` so `docker build .` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but a different solution (on Windows):

- I opened a console in my folder; my folder contains only `Dockerfile`
- `Dockerfile` content was `FROM ubuntu:20.04` (same as OP)
- Ran `docker build` knowing that I had a `Dockerfile` in my current folder
- I was getting the OP's same error message
- I stopped the Docker Desktop service
- Ran `docker build` again -- got `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`
- Ran `docker build Dockerfile` -- got `unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: C:\z\docker\aem_ubuntu20\Dockerfile`
- Ran `docker build .` -- got `error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.`
- Re-started the Docker Desktop service
- Ran `docker build .` -- success!
- Conclusion: `docker build PATH`, where `PATH` must be a **folder** name and that folder must contain a `Dockerfile`

Comment: Yes, it needs to be pointed at a folder that contains a Dockerfile and don't use the -f flag, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had a Linux symlink in the same directory as the Dockerfile. When running `docker build` from Windows 10, it gave me the `ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile`. I suspect Docker `docker build .` scans the directory and, if it can't read one file, it crashes. For me, I mounted the directory with WSL and removed the symblink.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error when running `docker` commands in a wrong directory. Just `cd` to the dir where your Dockerfile is, and all is good again.